# Create an IEnumerable object using bracket notation

Tags: c#

C# lets you create an ArrayList using notation like this:

```
var array = new ArrayList {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

How can I use that kind of notation for my own class?

For context, my goal is to create a method/constructor that takes a list of either `Type` or `IEnumerable<Type>` and concat them all together to make a single `List<Type>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to have an `Add(item)` method.

Comment: Thanks for marking this as a duplicate and pointing me to the right answer.  I didn't know the correct term to search for here :)